# Why does Promise.prototype.then always return promises?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to check my understanding of `Promise.prototype.then` is correct.

In the specs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) it says:

> If a handler function:
>
> returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the
> returned value as its value.

Is it not a bit strange for `.then` to return a promise object if I just returned something simple like `5` from the `.then`'s callback? How does this promise object resolve? It doesn't seem like it's fetching something from anywhere. Do promises like this always get fulfilled?

```js
function fetchDog(){
  fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random") 
  .then(response => 5) 
  .then(data => console.log(data))
};

fetchDog();
```

Comment: Yes, it is indeed like that.

Comment: As to *why*, imagine if `.then(response => 5)` simply returned `5`.  How would you write the next clause?  `.then` might return a value or a Promise for a value.  Can I add `7` to the result?  Can I call the `then` method of the result?  It becomes entirely unwieldy.  There was a [long discussion](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94) about whether it was appropriate to yield a Promise of a Promise. (The answer of "no" disappointed many of us.)  But that you always get back a Promise is what makes Promises work at all.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `then()` *must* return a promise according to the [Promises/A+ specification, 2.2.7](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40) (which is also reflected in the [EcmaScript specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen)).

At the time that `then()` is called on a promise A, a promise B is returned, but the then-callback is *not* executed at that moment. It is not known yet whether and how that promise B will settle. The then-callback will be called asynchronously, only after the base promise A, has resolved.

When A resolves, the then-callback will be called, and that call will determine *how* promise B will resolve. So when the callback returns 5, then that will be the value with which promise B resolves. If it is `undefined`, then that will be it. Only when the returned value is yet another promise C (or at least a thenable), there will be a cascade effect, and promise B will link its resolution to that of C.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function passed to `then` can't run until the promise it is associated with is resolved, but `then` has to return immediately, so `then` returns a promise.